# Read PDF in base64 format with a PDF library in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I have a base64 string and I need to read it with a Python library. I can do that with the following steps:

1. Decode the PDF in base64
2. Save it into a new file
3. Read it with libraries like PyPDF2

But since I can't create a new file, I need to read it using another process.  I tried using the BufferedWriter class, that is part of the `io` library but I believe that it is not the right way.

**Edit 1**

I can't create new files because I will be running the code in a serverless API host. And what I need to do is get the Base64 string and read it in a way that I can split each page into a new file and then save those files into a blob storage (but the split  and save part are easy, the problem is the "read Base64 string without creating a new file").

Comment: Oh, ok. I will elaborate more, but basicaly I can't create new files because I will be running the code in a serverless API host. And what I need to do is get the Base64 string and read it in a way that I can split each page into a new file and then save those files into a blob storage (but the split  and save part are easy, the problem is the "read Base64 string without creating a new file").

Comment: PDF is a binary format, not `base64`. Base64 is a way of encoding binary data as ASCII text. What you need to do is *decode* the base64 string with `base64.b64decode` into a byte array, then use a PDF library to read that byte array either directly or through a BytesIO object

Comment: BTW where does that base64 string come from? If it's from an HTTP request or email attachment, most HTTP/email libraries should be able to return the binary payload directly. You shouldn't have to decode the payload yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF is a binary file format, not a base64 string. Base64 is a way of encoding binary data as ASCII text.

What you need to do is decode the base64 string with [base64.b64decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode) into a byte array, then use a PDF library like [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) to read that byte array either directly or through a [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) object :

```
import base64
import io
from pypdf import PdfReader

buffer=base64.b64decode(thatString)
f=io.BytesIO(buffer)
reader = PdfReader(f)
page = reader.pages[0]
```

Comment: Two important notes: (1) the variable name "bytes" is not good as it shadows the builtin function (2) PyPDF2 is deprecated - use pypdf instead

Comment: Oops, fixed it.